# AS3 save previous frame while going in next to do something

Tags: actionscript-3

Is posible something like this: in frame1 I have some user interaction (drag drop graphics etc), when user click some button I open frame2 or frame3 where are fields for taking some input from user, then when user finish, I back him to frame1 but frame is not "reset"? I tried what described here, and I can even send data from frame 2 to frame 1 using global vars, but frame 1 is "reset" all user actions are clean, so is there a way in this situation to keep frame1 in memory or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous or next go to a frame if the frame is being initialized is natural. There's no way to save it. In other words, move the frame is The following concepts, `removeChild(previous-stage)`, `addChild(next-stage)`
In my experience, the script code to control the frame, increasing complexity are highly undesirable. Maintenance is difficult and in the future, the readability of the code is very poor. Recommend to handle than that in a single frame. Something like a single frame of the object location, size, status, and stored as a variable because it can restore it, it's more reasonable to think that.

Comment: Ok I understand...Than, it is better to find another way to take some input data from user, what you suggest? I need something like form, where I will take data from 4-5 text fileds (user needs to type), what is best and fastest way to do this?

Comment: As you try to configure the frame to do is frame the Movieclip you configure your thoughts. For example, you have a 3frame. so convert to 3MovieClip(each action is only Stage container role). and NextFrame is replaced one MovieClip set Hidden true or set Visible false. new MovieClip addChild to Stage. so if you prev to frame action is replaced current MovieClip set hidden false. and old MovieClip set hidden true.

Comment: bitmapdata.com this sounds interesting, and it seems that IS what I am looking for, tried but didn't succeed after reading your post, so can you try to explain me a bit better? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Flash & AS3 together you can put the code:

gotoAndStop(3); // 3 is the number of the frame

If you are using:

gotoAndPlay(3); // it will begin to play the frames from 3 till the timeline finds a stop mark.

So, you'll need to put a stop on the frame you want.
e.g. stop();

check out this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N9vE7wjoc4

Comment: I am using gotoAndStop(X), but when come back into frame where I started on same way, everything "rest" in state which is same when I load swf.

Comment: gotoAndStop(X) should stop on the frame! If it's going to another frame it's because something is sending it to there.
Try create a very simple example to check if the logic works.